# Sign custom *.cat file that uses WinUSB driver in Windows 10

Tags: windows, certificate, driver, code-signing

I need some clarification about driver signing in Windows 10.

We have working driver package that uses Winusb.sys driver that is signed from the start by Microsoft. But to install this driver to customer machine we have our own *.inf and 2 generated *.cat files for each supported platforms. Currently we have no issues using this driver in Windows 10 since modifications for Windows 8 support, but we want to add some additional hardware devices support in near future to driver, so it will be modified and need to be resigned.

The question is what certificate (Extended Validation (“EV”) Code Signing Certificate or just Standard Certificate) do we need to sign these *.cat files, so our driver can be installed correctly at Windows 10. Also is it necessary to submit out driver to Windows Hardware Developer Center Dashboard portal?

I saw [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_hardware_certification/archive/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10.aspx) and some other articles that states, EV certificate signing is needed only by kernel-mode drivers (it seems after 90 days of Win10 release also user-mode drivers), but WinUSB driver is kernel-mode and fully supported and initially signed by Microsoft. So again what kind of certificate do we need to sign *.cat files and do we need to submit them to Microsoft portal?

The files structure before signing looks like

```
driver
|--*.inf
|--*amd64.cat
|--*x86.cat
|--amd64
      |--WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
      |--winusbcoinstaller2.dll
|--i386
      |--WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
      |--winusbcoinstaller2.dll
|--ia64
      |--WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
      |--winusbcoinstaller2.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

My company also uses WinUSB for one of our devices. We currently use a "driver signing" certificate from Godaddy. Once the certificate is installed on your machine (they have step-by-step instructions for how to do this), you need to generate a pfx file and then you can use the signtool utility to sign the security catalog.

This link was a great resource for me: http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/